# Add annotation to type at runtime using javassist

Tags: java, java-8, java-bytecode-asm, javassist

I have the following code for the dynamic addition of annotation to java class

```
private void decorateWithSpecificAnnotation(final Set<Class<?>> domainClasses) {
    final ClassPool cp = ClassPool.getDefault();
    for (Class<?> c : domainClasses) {
        try {
            final CtClass cc = cp.get(c.getName());
            final ClassFile cfile = cc.getClassFile();
            final ConstPool cpool = cfile.getConstPool();
            final AnnotationsAttribute attr = new AnnotationsAttribute(cc.getClassFile().getConstPool(), AnnotationsAttribute.visibleTag);
            final Annotation annot = new Annotation(Document.class.getName(), cpool);
            attr.addAnnotation(annot);
            cfile.addAttribute(attr);
        } catch (NotFoundException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Unexpected error occured during dynamic domain decoration", e);
        }
    }
}
```

After calling the above method when I do the following i see that annotation is not present. What i am missing.

```
decorateWithSpecificAnnotation(domainClasses);
domainClasses.stream().forEach(d -> {
    System.out.println(d.isAnnotationPresent(Document.class));
});
```

Comment: Eddited answer with the `getNamesOfClassesWithAnnotationsAnyOf(..)` to search by annotation.

Answer (score 0):

When you use a `Class<?>` object, that class was already loaded by the class loader, and for that reason you cannot modify it. You can use another class loader to load again the class (but you would be able to use the class only with that cl). You could reload the class, but this is not that trivial, and probably even necessary thing to do.

---

If you pass a `Set<String>` with the full qualified class names, without using that classes (in any part of the code previously) it would work.

This operation of modify a class is normally one of the first process that should be performed.

You can use some libraries to scan the classpath without the need to load the class, an example of this is the [fast-classpath-scanner](https://github.com/lukehutch/fast-classpath-scanner).

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.github.lukehutch</groupId>
    <artifactId>fast-classpath-scanner</artifactId>
    <version>${fast-classpath.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

To use it, you can specify a base package to scan (it works recursively):, then you would re filter the class again (to ensure only classes of that package are uses, because it can detect also some classes that are not in that package, like annotations), filter the `package-info` and another custom filters.

This method finds all classes with the annotation `CustomAnnotation` on it.

```java
Set<String> classNames = new FastClasspathScanner(basePackage)
        .scan().getNamesOfAllClasses()
            .getNamesOfClassesWithAnnotationsAnyOf(CustomAnnotation.class)
        .stream()
        .filter(name -> name.startsWith(basePackage))
        .filter(name -> !name.endsWith("package-info"))
        .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Edit:

You also need to call the method that is used to load the class:

```
cc.toClass();
```

And finally if you want to keep the previos annotations, yo shouldn't create a new `AnnotationsAttribute` object, instead retrieve the current with:

```
AnnotationsAttribute attr = (AnnotationsAttribute) cfile
    .getAttribute(AnnotationsAttribute.visibleTag)
```

Comment: can i do like this new FastClasspathScanner("*.*").scan() ?

Comment: you don't have a base package?

Comment: normally you search in you app's package, is a custom annotation or a annotation from jdk, maybe ""?

Comment: so you are not using a custom annotation

Comment: I just want all the class which extends a particular class. Package name can vary and not know before hand.

Comment: You can try using empty string or no parameters, i've never used the library without a base package (and the documentation is not one of its strengths). Anyway i'm not sure what you are trying to do, you need to search by inheritance and the interface/class comes from jdk or another library?.

Comment: I used scanResult.getNamesOfClassesWithAnnotation but still the test is failing. That means this library also loads by class before i change. yes i am trying to load in the very brginning but no luck.

Comment: The library doesn't load the class. You should see at least an exception. I'm assuming that after that code you call `ctClass.toClass();` right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166944/discussion-between-saurabh-kumar-and-jose-da-silva).

Answer (score 0):

Your code is headed in the right direction, but the problem is that you need to convert the CtClass back into Java class. As [@jose-da-silva](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6201659/jose-da-silva) mentions, you cannot simply reload a class that is already loaded, but you can retransform it.

Annotations are a special case. Classes can be retransformed at runtime using [Instrumentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/Instrumentation.html). The restrictions of retransforms, quoting from the Javadoc, are:

> The retransformation may change method bodies, the constant pool and
>   attributes. The retransformation must not add, remove or rename fields
>   or methods, change the signatures of methods, or change inheritance.

Annotations reside in the constant pool so they are not subject to this restriction. See this example called [AnnotationBuilder](https://gist.github.com/nickman/647e1fbd52112ab3b15147cd99bbcd88). It's part of a larger library that uses Javassist to modify classes. Acquiring a Instrumentation instance is a bit involved, so this example uses ByteBuddy solely to acquire an instance. This is a brief example of the usage:

```
public static void main(String[] agrs) {
    log("Quickie Test");
    AnnotationBuilder ab = newBuilder("javax.xml.ws.soap.Addressing")
            .add("enabled", false)
            .add("required", true)
            .add("responses", Responses.NON_ANONYMOUS);
    try {
        final ClassPool cp = new ClassPool();
        cp.appendSystemPath();
        cp.appendClassPath(new LoaderClassPath(TestClass.class.getClassLoader()));
        final CtClass ctclazz = cp.get(TestClass.class.getName());
        ab.applyTo(ctclazz);
        final byte[] byteCode = ctclazz.toBytecode();
        final String target = TestClass.class.getName().replace('.', '/');
        log("Target:" + target);
        final ClassFileTransformer cft = new ClassFileTransformer() {               
            @Override
            public byte[] transform(ClassLoader loader, String className, Class<?> classBeingRedefined,
                    ProtectionDomain protectionDomain, byte[] classfileBuffer) throws IllegalClassFormatException {
                log("ClassName:" + className);
                if(target.equals(className)) {
                    log("Match !");
                    return byteCode;
                }
                return null;
            }
        };
        // ==============================================================================
        // There's several ways to acquire an Instrumentation instance
        // This one is the easiest
        // ==============================================================================
        Instrumentation ins = ByteBuddyAgent.install();
        try {               
            ins.addTransformer(cft, true);
            ins.retransformClasses(TestClass.class);
        } finally {
            ins.removeTransformer(cft);
        }
        log("Done");
        Addressing addr = TestClass.class.getAnnotation(Addressing.class);
        log("Annotation Present:" + addr!=null);
        if(addr!=null) {
            log("Enabled:" + addr.enabled());
            log("Required:" + addr.required());
            log("Responses:" + addr.responses().name());
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace(System.err);
    }       
}
```